# SSIS 2016 Access Denied

Tags: permissions, ssis, connectivity

I followed below steps after SQL Server and Integration Services, but I am still getting an error.

I added SQL service account in Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 13.0 properties which is under DCOM Config, and granted remote permissions to both service account and dba group account under Launch & Activation Permission & Access Permissions but still getting an error:

> connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer SERVER failed with the following error:
>
> Access is denied.
>
> By default only administrators have access to the Integration Services service. On Windows Vista and later, the process must be running with administrative privileges in order to connect to the Integration Services service.

Windows 2016 Standard and SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition.

Comment: Read this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941998/sql-server-2012-integration-services-failed-when-connecting-thru-ssms

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts come to mind:

1. You may have missed a step in the configuration setup - Check [Eliminating the "Access Is Denied" Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service#eliminating-the-access-is-denied-error)
2. Is this part of a SQL Server upgrade?  If so, you may need to install SSMS for that release.  The SSMS 17+ do not support connections to Integration Services on earlier versions of SQL Server.  [Previous SSMS releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms#previous-ssms-releases)

Comment: Thanks Derek. I uninstalled SSMS17+ and installed SSMS 16.5 version which works fine.

Comment: That's great, Sandeep!  Please upvote my answer as the resolution to your question.